# What is meta name="omni_page"?

Tags: html

What is `<meta name="omni_page" />`?  I only see it on Apple.com pages, and it doesn't look like anything I've seen in the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is used by the Omniture web analytics software.  http://www.omniture.com/

Comment: Interesting, Abode acquired Omniture (http://www.omniture.com/en/company/adobe_faq) so Apple is feeding analytical data to Adobe.

Comment: Oddly, the Omniture site doesn't use the tags, but this guess would make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `META` tag and `NAME` attribute are part of the w3c spec, see: [Specifying meta data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.1).

It does seem a bit strange that the meta data only includes a name, though.

Comment: Actually it's different on each page, and they seem to include values.  The front page has <meta name="omni_page" content="Apple - Index" /> , /mac/ has <meta name="omni_page" content="Mac - Index" /> , etc.

Answer (score 0):

From my search, I got this (for iPod Touch).

```
<meta name="omni_page" content="iPod touch - Index" />
```

"*omni_page*" basically suggest that the developer using a product from [**The Omni Group**](http://www.omnigroup.com/company/)

Their website suggests,

> The Omni Group is an elite team of
>   special forces who develop
>   productivity applications exclusively
>   for Mac OS X and iPhone.  We're known
>   for our awesome software,
>   gold-standard customer support, and
>   palpable geekery.

They also have a product called **OmniAppKit** which is an extension to Apple's `AppKit.framework`.

I think it's Omni Content generation which basically generates a meta tag for their pages for easy debugging purposes (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Could also be about Nuance's OmniPage OCR: http://www.nuance.com/imaging/products/omnipage.asp

Comment: You're the one assuming that the iPhone has something to do with it.

Comment: @Andrew Moore, my example has an example of the iPod Touch (and not iPhone) so I was wondering if the product works for iPod Touch (sorry, not iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Lower in the code, there's a line that points directly to Omniture.

```
    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript">
AC.GlobalNav.Instance = new AC.GlobalNav();
    </script>

<div id="top">
    <!-- SiteCatalyst code version: H.8. Copyright 1997-2006 Omniture, Inc. -->
```